# Flutter , show page offline with service worker

Tags: flutter, dart, service, worker

A client wants a web app for an event and he wants to avoid handling store problems such as validation etc... to go faster.

I already developped some app for android & iOS platform and not really for flutter web.

The client wants to access the app offline, not everything of course but at least some static information and one or two request saved in cache.

I looked for those thing in PWA and it usually use service worker (a pain in the ass to use), so i tried but there si so many element to keep in cache with flutter that it is hard to keep all and impossible to show the page because some element are missing.

So i have 2 questions :

- Did someone made a custom service worker and can show his web app offline ?
- is there a way to do this differently ? detect if the connection is offline and show the page saved elsewhere (i know about hive etc for example but i don't know if it can work with this kind of cache)

Thanks you !!!

Comment: I once came across this, never tried though https://medium.com/flutter-community/caching-in-flutter-for-web-42b3ae0e348f

Comment: well not yet possible : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60069